# Does Buddhist scripture mention Zoroastrianism?

Tags: comparative-religion, scripture, deva

Do any of the Buddhist texts mention anything about Zoroastrianism?

Has the Buddha ever met Zoroaster?

Answer (score 3):

**Do any of the Buddhist texts mention anything about Zoroastrianism?**

At the time of the Buddha the Indian spiritual scenario was under heavy influence of vedic brahminism which was on the west of Buddha's kingdom.

It is highly unlikely that Zoroastrianism which lay further west of Indus valley would cross the valley and influence Buddhist monks to get an honourable mention.

Also, it was only after the invasion of Alexander the Great that Indians came in heavy contact of Persia through the Satarps of Alexander. And his conquest was some 200 years after the Buddha. So it is unlikely that the Buddha himself would have encountered any human from Persia to tell him about Zoroastrianism as He met Jainas and Vedic brahmins.

Buddhist geography in the scriptures does not mention anything in the west not even Egypt.

**Has the Buddha ever met Zoroaster?**

Zoraster was hundreds or thousands of years prior to Gautama the Buddha so they might not have met in person.

But the Buddha is known to have a council with Gods and He was also possesor of super natural powers. So may be they would have had a chat in some different realms. But that only a Buddha can confirm for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no known mention of Zoroastrianism or Zoroaster in Buddhist texts, as far as I know, but there is a mention of "Gotama" in a Zoroastrian text.

According to a letter published in 1898 (from [here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/2B475187CC1D9471AB2F34CA2E178EF2/S0035869X00025417a.pdf/17_gotama_in_the_avesta.pdf)), the reference to Gotama in a Zoroastrian text likely refers to the Vedic sage [Gautama Maharishi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gautama_Maharishi), and not Gautama Buddha.

From the letter:

> I am able to discover an important identification of the Avestic
>   Gaotema with the Vedic Gotama. In the Rig-veda, Nodhas is Gotama's
>   son, who is called Naidhyangho  Gaotemahe in the Avesta. Hence it is
>   probable that the controversies  referred to in the Farvardin Yasht
>   was carried on by Zoroastrians against the Vedic poet Nodhas, and not
>   against Gaotama Buddha.
>
> ... The  Avesta  text  runs  thus:— "Through
>   their brightness and glory a man is born  who is a chief in assemblies
>   and meetings, who listens well to the holy words, who wishes for
>   wisdom, and who returns a victor from discussions with Gaotema,  the 
>   heretic." ...  Now  there  are  two  Gotamas  who  are  principally
>   familiar to us in the Vedic and the Buddhistic literature. One is
>   Rishi Gotama and the other Gotama Buddha. The latter is very well
>   known to us as  the  founder  of  Buddhism. The  former is one of the
>   seven rishis or sages mentioned in the Rig-veda.

Zoroaster seems to have lived before the time of the Buddha, far away in Persia, so it is unlikely that they have met each other. There is also no known record of that, as far as I know.

According to [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persecution_of_Buddhists#Sassanids), there was some persecution against Buddhists in Persia and Afghanistan by the Sassanids after Zoroastrianism became the official religion of Persia in 224 CE. Apart from this, I am not aware of other Buddhist-Zoroastrian encounters.

Answer (score 0):

I have never read Zoroastrianism mentioned in the Pali suttas. Since the Buddha called the lineage of Brahmin teachers a "string of blind men" because of none them had ever seen "God" or "Brahma", obviously he would have held the same view of any superstitious doctrine the believes in a creator god